# React native - Webview with javascript - document.cookie

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, cookies, webview

I have a problem with React Native, Webview and cookies.
So, I have a Webview, the source is html page some javascript.
Javascript tries to get cookies with `document.cookie` but it's empty with android.
It works fine with IOS.

My webview:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <WebView
    javaScriptEnabled={true} 
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={true}
    allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
    mixedContentMode={'always'}
    source={{uri:"https://mywebsite.com/"}} 
  />
</View>
```

And my javascript:

```
alert(document.cookie);
```

So on IOS, I have cookies, and on android, I have nothing ...

Do you know why?

Comment: Is it printing empty value in android? or alert is not doing anything? There was a bug that webview doesn't execute alert() in older chrome version webviews.

Comment: alert is not doing anything .. and code is stopping here.

Comment: then try on newer android/chromium versions and it should work.